# New flutter package not worknig

Tags: flutter, dart, google-fonts

pls help me out i'v tried everything. i did

flutter clean

flutter packages get

flutter packages upgrade

Restart Visual Studio (by using command: reload window)

take a look, my import package is not working...[this is the image:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7EmC.png)

Answer (score -1):

sorry, i already figure out myself. when a package is not working run the commands i provide, and then open your app (the app you are programming... well hit run). this will make VSCODE start actually running the commands and will run the {flutter pub get}. Try it out!

have a great one :)!